# Calculate the adjoint of the operator $D = \frac{1}{i} \frac{d}{dx}$

Tags: operator-theory, lp-spaces, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Let $p \in \mathbb{N}$, $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. We define on $L_p (a,b)$ the operator

$$D = \frac{1}{i} \frac{d}{dx}$$ with the domain $$\operatorname{dom}D = \left\{ u \in W_p^1 (a,b) \ | \ u (a) = u(b) = 0 \right\}$$

Show, that $D^* = \frac{1}{i} \frac{d}{dx}$ on $L_{p'} (a,b)$, with its domain being equal to $W_{p'}^1 (a,b)$ (where $p'$ is the conjugate exponent of $p$)

---

I honestly don't know how to do this. My approach goes like this:

$$\langle Du, f \rangle = \frac{1}{i} \int_a^b u'(x) \overline{f (x)} dx = \frac{1}{i}u(x) \overline{f(x)} \ |_a^b - \frac{1}{i}\int_a^b u(x) \frac{d \overline{f}}{dx} (x) dx = \int_a^b u(x) \overline{\frac{1}{i}} \frac{d \overline{f}}{dx}(x) dx = \langle u, D f \rangle $$

But I think this is just proving it for a special case, right?

Because where are we proving the fact that $D^*$ is on the $L_{p'} (a,b)$ space, with the domain $W_{p'}^1 (a,b)$?

Should I try using a different inner product? Which one? With the integrand taken to the p-th power?

Comment: Your proof looks fine. But I am not sure about the domain stuff. Surely if the operator is self adjoint then the adjoint has the same domain as the original operator?

Comment: @Daron My proof is really fine? Because it looks like I've only proved it for $L_2 (a,b)$, but what about e.g. $L_3 (a,b)$? And about the domain: I think it had to do with the fact that if $D : X \rightarrow Y$ then $D^* : Y^* \rightarrow X^*$ where $X^*, Y^*$ are dual spaces. So if here $Y = L_p (a,b)$, then $Y^* = L_{p'} (a,b)$. But because I need to take functions here which are differentiable (and they don't necessarily have to be that $f(a) = f(b) = 0$), I take the dual space of the Sobolev space namely $W_{p'}^1 (a,b)$? That's my theory at least

Comment: @Daron Also, we only showed that $D$ is symmetrical, and not necessarily self-adjoint

Comment: What is the domain of $D$? Is it $L_p$ or $W_p$?

Comment: @Daron $$\operatorname{dom}D = \left\{ u \in W_p^1 (a,b) \ | \ u (a) = u(b) = 0 \right\}$$

Comment: And what is the role of $L_p$?

Comment: @Daron  $$D \ : \ dom D \subset L_p (a,b) \ \rightarrow \ L_p (a,b)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because where are we proving the fact that $D^*$ is on the $L_{p'} (a,b)$ space, with the domain $W_{p'}^1 (a,b)$?

You want to prove that $D^* f  \in L_{p'}$ for all $f \in W_{p'}^1$.

This follows almost from the definitions:

$$ W_{p'}^1(a,b)   = \left \{ f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R: \frac{df}{dx} \text{ exists and } \frac{df}{dx} \in L_{p'}(a,b) \right\}$$

Since $D^* f =   \frac{1}{i} \frac{df}{dx}$ it should be easy to see $D^* f \in L_{p'}$